# When i create a new react native project with typescript and add styled components, the components generated by styled components props dont show

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

[component props not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1oXn.png)

No props of any component are showing

[creation of component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msbGq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/styled-components-react-native

Comment: I have it, i notices that the problem is something related to inference, because if i define the return type on "export const Container = styled.View``" the props appear on the generated component